# What does this mean :"sshd 5927 root 3u IPv4 66110 0t0 TCP 192.168.1.165:ssh->43.229.53.76:60 673 (ESTABLISHED)"

Tags: sshd

I tried to check who is connecting to my server and got this line I could not recognized. I used `sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\<ssh\>'`.

And these lines looks odd to me:

`sshd      5921       sshd    3u  IPv4  66008      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.165:ssh->43.229.53.76:59
605 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      5922       root    3u  IPv4  66056      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.165:ssh->43.229.53.76:60
008 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      5923       sshd    3u  IPv4  66056      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.165:ssh->43.229.53.76:60
008 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      5924       root    3u  IPv4  66082      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.165:ssh->43.229.53.76:60
407 (ESTABLISHED)`

The address is from HongKong and I am not aware of why that could happen.

Comment: might be interesting to check ps on those PIDs and their parent PIDs to check which processes started these connections.

Answer (score 0):

Established TCP connection is probably authentication attempt, which doesn't mean that the authentication was successful. It is probably just a noise, but of course, you should check the PIDs as proposed in the comment, if the `sshd` process is in `[preauth]` mode or `[postauth]` -- should be visible in normal `ps`.